# Tradingview chart widget apply settings change

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

With the tradingview chartwidget i want to make a settings/options change in js and apply it to the chart without doing a full reload (chart.reload())
on the [tradingview](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) widget page there is an apply button which seems to work much faster than chart.reload(). anyone knows anything? Thx

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [applyOverrides](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Widget-Methods#applyoverridesoverrides) (link requires membership in the GitHub repo, which is obtained by signing the license agreement).

Normally I would add more about the solution, but the library isn't open source and its [licensing terms](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/) might prohibit reproducing any of its documentation.